# Can not connect to internet/struggling with network configuration

Tags: networking, server, internet, dhcp

Trying to use Ubuntu server for a minecraft server with friends. Not had much luck. Basically when it gets to the DHCP part of the install for the network configuration, there is no IP address and the box above it eth0 says not connected. I don't know how to make it connect. I've tried several options such as using the sudo nano command thing (DHCP is set to true), and when I try to use the resolvconf command it won't let me and says I need to download it, which I can't because of no connection to the internet. I'm using an old laptop, not a desktop, to do this server, and I know it said somewhere a direct connection with an ethernet cable is better, but that's not an option for me. Laptop is an HP Pavilion dm4.

Comment: DHCP gets an IP from the router.  How is your router set?  It may have settings like range of IPs to assign, and maximum number of IPs.

Comment: *"sudo nano command thing"* - Please tell us what files you edited and how you edited them.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there may be an issue with your network drivers. First, try running the command "**sudo lshw -C network**" to see if your network device is detected by Ubuntu. If it is detected, try running "**sudo ifconfig eth0 up**" to bring up the interface manually.

If this still doesn't work, try plugging the laptop into your router or modem directly (if possible) and see if it gets an IP address that way. That may help narrow down the issue.

Also, double-check that your router is set up to assign IP addresses via DHCP and that there are no IP address conflicts on your network.

If all else fails, try downloading the necessary packages and drivers on another computer and copying them over to the Ubuntu installation on a USB drive or via a shared folder.